# asy there any way to change color of UIWebView of Iphone Application

Tags: iphone

I am using webview to display Data from RSS Feed Can I change color of WebView to Black From white. 
I have declare outlet in xib file named RemainingRssViewController
and i am diplaying it from root view controller the code is

```
NSString *htmlstring =[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex] objectForKey: @"description"];
   NSURL *baseUrl;
baseUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:feedurl];

    [anotherViewController.maintext loadHTMLString:htmlstring baseURL:baseUrl];
  //maintext is the UIWebVeiw outlet in anotherViewController.
```

Comment: Do you want to change the background color of the UIWebView itself, or just the background color of the space the UIWebView takes up? For example, could you set the CSS background-color property of your page to be the color you want?

Comment: @golfromeo Thanks for replying 

my data is store in NSMutable array from xml feed I want to display it in UIWebView
I have done It now I want to change the textcolor to White And Background Color to black.
Is it possible...

Comment: Okay... so I'm assuming that you're putting the text inside the UIWebView as HTML... then I would suggest using the following CSS: `body { color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000000; }`. If you're unsure how to implement CSS, then let me know.

Comment: yes brother 
I am new to iphone and i don't no how creat css for iphone appliction and how to implement it.
Thanks....

Comment: Ok, that's fine- if you could post the code in your question of where you insert the XML text into the web view, I'll answer your question and provide you with the code to make the background color styles you want.

Comment: you can Check the Q I have edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks good.

With this code:

`NSString *htmlstring =[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex] objectForKey: @"description"];`

You set up an HTML string to go in the UIWebView. However, it's not actually HTML, because right now it's just text. To solve this, we'll instead make the "htmlstring" to be styled HTML with the text from the XML feed.

For example:

`NSString *textString = [[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex] objectForKey:@"description"];`

`NSString *htmlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type='text/css'>body { color:#FFFFFF; background-color: #000000; }</style></head><body>%@</body></html>",textString];`

Then, when the "htmlstring" is placed inside the UIWebView, it will be styled as you would like it to be.

Comment: Thanks it work now please can you tell me how to change the text style to Arial and size to 10. i am sorry for such basic question but em very new to programming

Comment: Put this after `background-color: #000000;` : `font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;`

Comment: Thanks I have done it.... @Douwe best of luck in worldcup final.....

You guys are very helpfull.